# How to tar a folder in HDFS?

Tags: hdfs

Just like Unix command `tar -czf xxx.tgz xxx/`, is there a method can do the same thing in HDFS? I have a folder in HDFS has over 100k small files, and want to download it to local file system as fast as possible. `hadoop fs -get` is too slowly, I know `hadoop archive` can output a `har`, but it seems cannot solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see here,

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7519

it is not possible to perform tar operation using hadoop commands. This has been filed as an improvement as I mentioned above and not resolved/available yet to use.

Hope this answers your question.

Regarding your scenario - having 100k small files in HDFS is not a good practice. You can find a way to merge them all (may be by creating tables through Hive or Impala from this data) or move all the small files to a single folder in HDFS and use `hadoop fs -copyToLocal <HDFS_FOLDER_PATH>;` to get the whole folder to your local along with all the files in it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do know it's not a good practice, and have a plan to refactor, but it need time.
The HADOOP-7519 is definitely what I want, but it seems not active. I'm not expert in HDFS and Linux File System, I don't know if there is a possibility to implement `tar` and `gzip` using MR or Spark?

Comment: Currently no, we cannot use tar/zip files in HDFS and run MapReduce or Spark operations on them. It is not supported.

Try reading this Relevant page for using TAR FS: https://github.com/JDatta/TarFileSystem

Please mark the answer as solved, if it answered your question so others might find it helpful.